# How to apply different formulas to column based on condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have been looking at how to perform these tasks for a while and couldn't find any help on Google.

Background:

I have an excel with different maintenance items for a product. Each item has a different maintenance schedule. For example, oil has to be changed every 24 weeks, interiors have to be disinfected every week. Once the first date of the maintenance is introduced, it will automatically cross out when reaching the specified interval.

This functionality is "hard-coded" on each cell

Request:

I want to make this excel more flexible. I want to be able to select the maintenance interval in the first sheet and it will automatically apply this condition to the item.

Is there any way to select different formulas based on a condition?

Example: I set the oil change for 20 weeks for 1 product but for the other product, I would like to set it to 24 weeks. Is there any way of doing this without changing the underlying formula manually?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes; Place each of those numbers in a separate cell, label them accordingly (so you know what the numbers stands for), then use an absolute cell reference *(e.g `$A$1` if that is where the value is)* instead of the actual number in your formula.

Comment: Your requirement is possible, but you should provide a sample about the Tables and the results you need.